# Не удается подключиться к бд

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Пишу в Linux. Необходимо подключиться к `Access` бд,но `Qt`говорит что нет такого драйвера `QODBC`, хотя в предложенных он имеется

```
 QString _dbPath=QDir::currentPath()+"/DB.mdb";
    if(!QFile::exists(_dbPath))//Проверяем наличие файла бд
    {
       qDebug()<<"Не удалось найти файл базы данных";
        return;
    }
    if(!QSqlDatabase::contains("DB"))//Если обьект QSqlDatabase уже создан,то не перезаписываем его
    {
        QSqlDatabase ADOCon = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC","DB");
        ADOCon.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+_dbPath);
        ADOCon.setPassword("pass");
        try {
            ADOCon.open();
        } catch (...) {
            qDebug()<<"Не удалось подключиться к базе данных";
            return;
        }
    }
```

Вот сообщение об ошибки:

```
QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC3 QODBC QPSQL QPSQL7
```

В `windows` Точно такой же код работает нормально.Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Какова версия QT? Есть такой [баг](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49420), может быть в новых версиях исправлено?

Comment: Может быть сам libqsqlodbc.so есть, но ссылается на несуществующие библиотеки. Сделайте ldd ./libqsqlodbc.so в папке с плагином и посмотрите, нет ли там ненайденных зависимостей

Comment: `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` переменная окружения должна указывать на список вaших плагинов. Как то так `export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/xxxx/qtsdk-xxxxx/qt/plugins/`